# Распарсить JSON в Retrofit2, не зная API

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Есть [сайт профкома универера](http://pks-zntu.org.ua). Хочу добавить новости с главной страницы к себе в приложуху. На нём я точно знаю что JSON, но сам API мне не дают (точнее мне пообещали дать, но теперь морозятся). Как можно распарсить его при помощи Rertrofit, что бы добыть JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как можно распарсить его при помощи Rertrofit, что бы добыть JSON?

Если сервер не предоставляет API, или же у Вас к нему нет доступа, то и воспользоваться Вы этим API (которое, в Вашем случае, отдает JSON) не сможете.

---

Могу предложить альтернативный вариант – просто распарсить HTML, например, с помощью Jsoup.

Всякие JSON, XML, безусловно, хороши, но если сервер не отдает их, то остается только вариант с парсингом HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit, по крайней мере вторая его версия, не задумывался как JSON-ориентированное решение, и, таким образом, может работать с чем угодно (JSON, XML, YAML, CSV, HTML, etc).
Вы всегда сможете привинтить к нему конвертеры любой сложности, включая инфраструктуру для JSoup.

Допустим, нужно показывать элементы со следующей структурой:

```java
final class NewsEntry {

    final String title;
    final String excerpt;

    NewsEntry(final String title, final String excerpt) {
        this.title = title;
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }

}
```

Retrofit-сервис, который сможет вытянуть данные со странички можно описать приблизительно так:

```java
interface INewsService {

    @GET("/")
    @JsoupQuery(
            cssQueries = {
                    ".blog > .items-leading > div",
                    ".blog > .items-row > div"
            },
            deserializerClass = NewsEntriesJsoupDeserializer.class
    )
    Call<List<NewsEntry>> getNews();

}
```

`@JsoupQuery` здесь -- кастомная аннотация, призванная облегчить декларативное описание обработки HTML-документов.

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@interface JsoupQuery {

    String[] cssQueries();

    Class<? extends IJsoupDeserializer<?>> deserializerClass();

}
```

Обратите внимание, что JSoup поддерживает множественные выражения, разделённых с помощью запятой `,`, но ради удобства мы сможем добавить поддержу немного более комфортной записи с помощью множественных значений `cssQueries`.
`deserializerClass` -- класс, который знает, как правильно пропарсить `Elements`:

```java
interface IJsoupDeserializer<T> {

    T deserialize(Elements elements);

}
```

И, собственно, как бы можно было десериализировать HTML-элементы, возвращаемые с помощью `cssQueries` выше:

```java
final class NewsEntriesJsoupDeserializer
        implements IJsoupDeserializer<List<NewsEntry>> {

    private NewsEntriesJsoupDeserializer() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<NewsEntry> deserialize(final Elements elements) {
        if ( IS_JDK_8 ) {
            return elements.stream()
                    .map(NewsEntriesJsoupDeserializer::parse)
                    .collect(toList());
        } else {
            final List<NewsEntry> newsEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( final Element element : elements ) {
                newsEntries.add(parse(element));
            }
            return newsEntries;
        }
    }

    private static NewsEntry parse(final Element element) {
        return new NewsEntry(
                element.select("div.page-header a").text(),
                element.select("dl.article-info + p").text()
        );
    }

}
```

(* `IS_JDK_8` -- простая отсебятина: люблю Java 8)

Как я уже сказал выше, Retrofit поддерживает множество форматов.
Достаточно просто реализовать конвертер, который свяжет "сырой" ввод с аннотацией `@JsoupQuery`:

```java
final class JsoupQueryConverterFactory
        extends Factory {

    private final String baseUri;

    private JsoupQueryConverterFactory(final String baseUri) {
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
    }

    static Factory getJsoupQueryConverterFactory(final String baseUri) {
        return new JsoupQueryConverterFactory(baseUri);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
        final JsoupQuery jsoupQuery = findJsoupQuery(annotations);
        if ( jsoupQuery == null ) {
            return super.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
        }
        final String cssQuery = getCompoundCssQuery(jsoupQuery.cssQueries());
        final IJsoupDeserializer<?> jsoupDeserializer = instantiate(jsoupQuery.deserializerClass());
        return (Converter<ResponseBody, Object>) responseBody -> {
            final Document document = Jsoup.parse(responseBody.byteStream(), null, baseUri);
            final Elements elements = document.select(cssQuery);
            return jsoupDeserializer.deserialize(elements);
        };
    }

    private static JsoupQuery findJsoupQuery(final Annotation[] annotations) {
        if ( IS_JDK_8 ) {
            return Stream.of(annotations)
                    .filter(annotation -> annotation instanceof JsoupQuery)
                    .map(annotation -> (JsoupQuery) annotation)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);
        } else {
            for ( final Annotation annotation : annotations ) {
                if ( annotation instanceof JsoupQuery ) {
                    return (JsoupQuery) annotation;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String getCompoundCssQuery(final String[] cssQueries) {
        if ( IS_JDK_8 ) {
            return Stream.of(cssQueries)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        } else {
            final StringBuilder cssQueryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for ( int i = 0; i < cssQueries.length; i++ ) {
                final String cssQuery = cssQueries[i];
                if ( i > 0 ) {
                    cssQueryBuilder.append(", ");
                }
                cssQueryBuilder.append(cssQuery);
            }
            return cssQueryBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    private static <T> T instantiate(final Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            final Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return constructor.newInstance();
        } catch ( final InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException ex ) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

И, собственно, сам пример:

```java
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://pks-zntu.org.ua";

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(getJsoupQueryConverterFactory(BASE_URL))
            .build();
    final INewsService newsService = retrofit.create(INewsService.class);
    final List<NewsEntry> newsEntries = newsService.getNews().execute().body();
    if ( IS_JDK_8 ) {
        newsEntries.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.title + " => " + e.excerpt));
    } else {
        for ( final NewsEntry e : newsEntries ) {
            System.out.println(e.title + " => " + e.excerpt);
        }
    }
}
```

Пример усечённого вывода:

> УВАГА! Соціальні стипендії! => Комісія соціального захисту профкому студентів ЗНТУ ...
>   Центр сприяння працевлаштуванню студентів ... => На Ярмарку ви зможете особисто поспілкуватись ...
>   ...